# autoFixOnSave only for certain file extensions

Tags: eslint

Is it possible to configure eslint to autoFixOnSave only for certain file extensions ? For instance, if the file is .ts it should autoFixOnSave but if its .js it shouldnt.

Answer (score 1):

As you mentioned `autoFixOnSave`, I'm assuming you are using *VSCode*. So you need to install and configure both [vscode-eslint](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode-eslint) and [vscode-tslint](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode-tslint).

Your `settings.json` should contain:

```
{
  "eslint.autoFixOnSave": false,
  "tslint.autoFixOnSave": true
}
```